# keep loging missing server connection for kctconnectioninvalidatednotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, face-recognition

When my project running face recognition module will continue to output:

> Missing server connection for kCTConnectionInvalidatedNotification.

[image]

What could be causing the issue? how can I resolve it?

Comment: Have you got any solutions or reasons for this?

Comment: I am getting similar kind of error in my VOIP project.

Comment: Any Solution did you find ?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Could be a URL request of your app isn't working, as you have dropped network connection. Either that or ATS is enabled with no exception domain.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12786 check this.

Comment: and this one also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53617/connect-to-server-option-missing

Comment: This error comes from the private `CoreTelephony` framework, and usually is not related to the app. In fact, if it is related, I recommend you to send sysdiagnose logs to Apple for a bug report. But first you'd have to read the logs to ensure it is because of your face recognition module.

Answer (score 1):

If you used some socket connection , you have to pay attention:

1. To send heart bit package periodically to your server.
2. When client loses client, you have to reconnect to your server (unless you don't want it).